# teradata sql problem: how to calculate the time difference in different columns with previous row order by another column?

Tags: sql, teradata

It may sound not a new question here. But it is a little tricky here....

I want to apply for a similar sql like this below in teradata...

```
sel (col2- LAG(col1, 1)) minute OVER (ORDER BY session_id)
from data
```

I want to calculate the time difference by minutes between col1 and col2 ordered by session_id. So there are three columns here...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the datatype of columns `col1` and `col2`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the syntax you want is:

```
select (col2- LAG(col1) OVER (ORDER BY session_id)) day(4) to minute
from data
```

Note that `1` is not necessary; it is the default for `LAG()`.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. But it returns the error of 7453, saying interval field overflow...

Comment: `day(4) to minute` can handle up to 9999 days, which is pretty big (27 years) -- especially if you are asking for a duration in minutes. Also, I imagine that you really want `col1 - lag(col1)`.

Comment: i found one date with 2999 which is the proble I guess... but when I select the timeframe using select (col2- LAG(col1) OVER (ORDER BY session_id)) day(4) to minute
from data where col1 between '2020-04-01' and '2020-04-15' it shows the error of 6760..saying ivalid timestamp... it is rather strange that both col1 and col2 is valid timestamp...

Comment: col1 and col2 may be timestamps, but 2020-04-01 is not a valid timestamp. It's a date.

Comment: `where col1 between date '2020-04-01' and date '2020-04-15'

Comment: Whoa, I never knew you could do it that way. Is Teradata implicitly casting col1 as a date here?